# Как подключиться к удаленному серверу веб-Api, через Эмулятор Android в Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, localhost, xamarin.forms

Не могу получить доступ к серверу Api, созданный на ASP.NET Core. Доступ нужен для отображения данных на Android.

То есть в приложении Api есть доступ к базе данных, а в приложении Xamarin.Forms нужно получить эти самые данные.

Если отлаживать приложение Api, я с лёгкостью получаю доступ к данным.
Вот такая адресная строка — http://localhost:61343/api/room

В приложении на Xamarin.Forms хочу получить данные:

```
var client = new WebClient();

var response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:61343/api/room");

RoomListView.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Room>>(response);
```

Ошибка **System.AggregateException:** 'One or more errors occurred. (Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused))'

Ошибка связана с подключением к Api.

Поискав на просторе Интернета — Я **не могу подключиться с Эмулятора к Api потому, что у меня Api работает на локальном хосте**. Чтобы мне подключиться с Эмулятора к данным мне нужно...

Дк вот:
Что мне надо сделать, чтобы **подключаться к Api через Эмулятор**?

Comment: 1. `WebClient` уже давно является устаревшим механизмом в C#, стоит читать документацию, а не копировать первый попавшийся код из интернета. 2. `localhost` - это адрес текущей OS, другими словами, вы говорите "ей, подключись-ка к моему же устройству". То есть, если вы пишете `localhost` и запускаете это на эмуляторе, то система пытается подключится к саму android устройству, а не к внешнему компьютеру. При подключении к сети, будь то роутер или провайдер, вам выдают уникальный IP адрес сети (локальный роутера обычно `192.168.1.*`), вот вам надо как минимум использовать его в подключении.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Как мне можно использовать Ip адрес для подключения к одному серверу?

То есть как мне можно подключиться к одному Ip адресу с «моего устройства» и эмулятора?

Comment: Я вам выше уже сказал ведь как, не? Ваш роутер дает устройству при подключении уникальный IP адрес, его и используйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ

У меня действительно такой Ip адрес — 192.168.1 

Я не понимаю куда его вставлять, что с ним делать?

Comment: Если ты хочешь сказать замени в адресной строке на http://192.168.1:61343/api/room. Это не работает

Comment: Да, это я и хочу сказать. Не работает - не объяснение проблемы ведь. Я как минимум вижу то, что IP у вас не полноценный, он должен состоять из 4-х цифр, разделенных точкой (`***.***.***.***`). Также не забывайте про защиту OS брандмауэр и всякие антивирусы могут блокировать соединение. Также не забываем, что сам сервер должен быть настроен на принятие внешних запросов, а я лично не знаю как вы asp.net хостите...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ввожу в адресную строку http://192.168.0.1:61343/api/room — Не удаётся получить доступ к сайту.

Брандмауэр отключён.
Как мне настроить сервер на принятие внешних запросов?

Comment: http://192.168.0.1:61343/api/room ввожу на своем устройстве не в эмуляторе

Comment: Вы уверены, что `192.168.0.1` - это ваш компьютер? Обычно это Ip роутера или некой конечной точки. `Как мне настроить сервер на принятие внешних запросов` - зависит от того, что за сервер, ведь asp.net можно [разместить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy) много где. Короче, ваша цель - добиться того, чтоб в простом браузере открывался ваш сайт без проблем, с указанием IP вашего компьютера в этой сети, где находится и эмулятор. Как настроить, что, где - не скажу, ибо тут много всяких переменных, о которых я не знаю (сервер, оборудование и др.).

Comment: Даааа, именно это мне и надо! Вот только я целый день бьюсь с этим и не могу этого сделать.

Comment: Адрес хоста в локальной сети нужен. На компе с сервером откройте консоль и нсберите ipconfig, там будет адрес. Либо посмотрите свойства сетевого подключения по локальноф сети. Там будет адрес 192.168.0.x, он вам и нужен для подключения. Там будет еще основной шлюз 192.168.0.1 - это адрес роутера, он вам не нужен, не перепутайте. Адреса DNS вам тоже не нужны.

Comment: @aepot, у меня адрес 192.168.0.100 если я ввожу его вместо localhost у меня такая же ошибка —  Не удаётся получить доступ к сайту.

Comment: Похожий вопрос был [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131658/xamarin-connect-to-locally-hosted-web-service), но я никак не могу понять, что нужно мне нужно поменять, чтобы подключаться к api через эмулятор?

Возможно есть вариант развернуть приложение api, тогда как это сделать? и где лучше это сделать?

Comment: Забудьте вы про андройд, эмулятор, xamarin и прочее. Сделайте сначала рабочий сайт, который будет доступен по адресу **вашего компьютера в этой сети**, для этих тестов достаточно простого браузера. Как я вам и говорил выше, причин отсутствия подключения может быть несколько: 1. Не правильная настройка сервера (я не знаю, где у вас размещается asp.net, может это iis, может nginx, может просто консолька через дебаг студии (что странно)). 2. Защита компьютера блокирует соединение. 3. Роутер блокирует (обычно для одной сети нет). 4. Неверный IP или порт.